# WordPress - Stability Theme - custom icon color on mouse hover

Tags: css, wordpress, icons, themes, customization

I'm using WordPress with the [Stability](http://dan-fisher.com/#stability_html) theme installed.

When not hovering over an icon, it looks red (by default). This can be easily changed by changing the theme's skin in the options menu.

However, when the mouse is hovering over the icon, [it turns black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHzGN.png). This is independent of the theme's skin and I cannot, for the for the life of me, change this color to something else. I've been using the element inspector in my browser and turning CSS properties on and off all day and couldn't zero in to the property that defines that color.

Any ideas on how I might be able to change it? The theme's documentation sais nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the background colour by editing this bit of css, or by overriding it with your own duplicate in a custom css file.

```
.no-touch .icon-box.icon-box-animated .icon:hover::before {
background-color: #2f2f2f;
transform: scale(0.9, 0.9);
}
```

Its currently located in: http://stability.dan-fisher.com/css/theme-elements.css on line 1302